# JS - Create spaces in string until it gets certain width

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a select tag in html, which I append the options in javascript/jquery.

The problem is the content is dynamic, it's price amounts with interest.

I would like to have the price amount in the left and the interest in the right, but I can't figure it out how.

In this case, I created the white spaces hardcoded, which looks pretty weird as you can see:

[image]

Is there a way to throw the second column all the way to the right and keeps it aligned?

Thanks.

Comment: I think there is not a proper way for this unless you code your custom select.

Comment: This isn't a mono-spaced font, you won't be able to get it perfect using spaces. The Nx part is going to cause problems. You may be better off putting each item in it's own tag and using css to space it all out, or a table.

Comment: @JDunken is right about the monospaced font. But that would look weird. From a UX perspective: are you sure that the user has to see all 12 choices at once? What about showing a slider instead where the user could select the quantity and see the prices updated next to it?

Comment: Thanks, guys. I will find another font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution using a monospace font:

```js
const wordPairs = [
  ['hello', 'world'],
  ['hello', 'there!'],
  ['why', 'hello!!!'],
  ['hey', 'bro'],
  ['hi', '...']
];
const maxChars = Math.max(...wordPairs.map(pair => pair.join('').length));
const minDistance = 5;
const targetLength = maxChars + minDistance;
const select = document.getElementById('select');
for (const pair of wordPairs) {
  const option = document.createElement('option');
  const texts = [pair[0], '', pair[1]];
  while (texts.join('').length < targetLength) {
    texts[1] += String.fromCharCode(160);
  }
  option.innerHTML = texts.join('');
  select.appendChild(option);
}
```

```html
<select id="select" style="font-family: monospace">
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks! with my current font, this is the best I can do.

Answer (score 0):

If you used a font like Ariel, where all letters and spaces are the same wifth, you could simply count the number of characters and add the needed spacing. 
You will need to know 
the width of the select - width of left words  - width of right words